# python tempfile.mkdtemp with everyone permission

Tags: python, temporary-files

I want to create a temporary directory with every one permission to read, write and  execute. I also want to be able to run it on both, windows and linux. i have tried tempfile.mkdtemp(), but it is with very limiting permission.

does anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change permissions with `os.chmod`:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> t = tempfile.mkdtemp()
>>> import os
>>> os.chmod(t, 0o444)
>>> t
'/var/folders/pg/j27n0zds1bq9pzgl9g6bm9yw0000gn/T/tmpgbuhokn7'
```

In bash:

```
dr--r--r--    2 me  staff    64 21 Nov 17:48 tmpgbuhokn7
```

If you want other permissions, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.chmod)

Comment: oh, i see that i wrote '0777' instead of 0o777, thanks